# Удалил случайно папку system в opencart

Tags: opencart

Помогите удалил случайно папку system в opencart. Что делать?

Comment: Обращаться в службу поддержки хостинга и смотреть есть ли у них автоматическое резервирование. Смотреть есть ли у Вас дампы старые или новые....ну и вообще в этой папке есть чего кастомного?..если она у всех опенкартов одинаковая(в рамках версии) - просто скачайте исходники опенкарта соответствующей версии и залейте к себе...и на будущее раставляйте права доступа таким образом чтобы не удалить ничего нечаянно.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: рад, что мои комментарии Вам помогли. Делайте резервные копии на будущее :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Когда вы загружали на хост ваш сайт, то у вас на домашнем компе должен был остаться сайт. Найдите там папку `systems` и загрузите обратно. Если у вас нет бэкапа, то вам нужно скачать такую же версию опенкарта, какая у вас, и оттуда взять вашу папку.

Answer (score 0):

Если доступ по фтп имеется (или через панель управления хоста - файл менеджер), просто залейте system (если не осталось, то скачайте opencart той же версии) в корень сайта. 99% что разницы не заметите. Там максимум что лежало невозвратное - это кеши расширений. Но если у вас было всё правильно установлено и настроено до того, они восстановятся после первой прогрузки сайта. Удачи.

З.Ы.Насмешили по-доброму. Помню, как в 2000х, когда ещё с винтами ходили друг к другу расшаривать музыку и фильмы, часто бегали по друзьям которые то "случайно" пол винды затирали, то вовсе сносили, тупо удаляя файлы которые им казались подозрительными или ненужными. Навеяло))

Comment: Да уж сам в шоке))